# function is introducing NaN's in R

Tags: r

I am working with dataframe `ds` and this code:

`ds[,-1] = apply(ds[,-1],2,function(x){x/sum((x))})`

This function should just be running through each cell in each column. Each cell is then divided by the sum of the column. However, after running this function, some columns are populated with NaNs and I am not sure why. How do I go about figuring out why there are NaNs? Is there a way to change my function so I do not get NaNs?

`df` looks something like this.

```
sample a b  c
x    2 1  2
x1   3 0 45
```

Running str:

`> str(df)`

`'data.frame':  99322 obs. of  257 variables:
 $ sample  : int  100021 1000032 100013 10001134 100014568 100014566 104600161 100017 1000188 10002 ...
 $ FT579627: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT579617: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT579618: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578292: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578294: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578295: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578296: num  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
 $ FT578297: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578321: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578322: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578323: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578324: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578325: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578326: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578327: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578329: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578330: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FT578405: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  [list output truncated]`

Comment: Can you provide an example of a dataframe that you are using? I suspect you may have a column with 0 sum, hence you get integer/float by zero division which results in NaN.

Comment: @HrantDavtyan Yes, I think this is correct. Do you know how I would avoid getting a 0 sum? Or at least, how to avoid getting NaN's? I'm assuming some kind of `ifelse`, but being very new to R, im not sure how to implement this.

Comment: can't reproduce with your example (using ds <- `read.table(header=TRUE,text="...")`)

Comment: `dput(df)` would be best, but if too unwieldy, can you give us `summary(df)` or `str(df)` ?

Comment: you could write `if (sum(x) == 0) 0 else x/sum(x)` or similar

Comment: is the data frame you've posted before or after applying the scaling function?

Comment: @Jennifer If you avoid getting NaN, you have to get something else instead. You may drop rows with NaNs, or transform your dataframe before dividing by sum (square up, take abs etc.) or convert them to 0, as suggested above, or use some other approach. Your decision highly depends on what problem you are trying to solve. Based on that dropping or converting to 0s may or may not be the best approach.

Comment: @BenBolker Hi Ben, this is after I applied the function. Before the function, all the columns were called as int.

Comment: @Jennifer: Just because an object is of mode `int` is no barrier to some of the elements being `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps removing the NA's?

```
ds[,-1] = apply(ds[,-1],2,function(x){x/sum((x, na.rm=TRUE))})
```